# How to pivot using multiple columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am having trouble creating pivot table that follows the schema described below.
For example, with the following table (not all records are shown here):

| Route | Bus_Fare_Payment_Method | Total_Annual_Household_Income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Route 1 | 10-Ride Pass | $15K To $19K |
| Route 1 | 10-Ride Pass | $15K To $19K |
| Route 1 | 10-Ride Pass | $25K To $29K |
| Route 1 | 10-Ride Pass | $60K Or More |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 10 | 10-Ride Pass | $30K To $39K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $10K To $14K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $10K To $14K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $10K To $14K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $10K To $14K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $15K To $19K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $20K To $24K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $20K To $24K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $20K To $24K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $20K To $24K |
| Route 101 | All Day Pass Reduced | Under $10K |
| Route 101 | Other | Under $10K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $10K To $14K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $25K To $29K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $30K To $39K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $40K To $49K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $60K Or More |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $60K Or More |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $60K Or More |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 101 | Regular Cash Fare | $10K To $14K |
| Route 101 | Regular Cash Fare | $10K To $14K |
| Route 101 | Regular Cash Fare | $10K To $14K |
| Route 101 | Regular Cash Fare | $10K To $14K |

I would like to produce the following table:

| Route | Bus_Fare_Payment_Method | $10K To $14K | $15K To $19K | $20K To $24K | $25K To $29K | $30K To $39K | $40K To $49K | $60K Or More | Under $10K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Route 1 | 10-Ride Pass |  | 2 |  | 1 |  |  | 1 |  |
| Route 1 | 31-Day Adult |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 1 | All Day Pass Reduced |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 1 | Other |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 1 | Reduced Fare |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 8 |
| Route 10 | 10-Ride Pass |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  |  |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | 4 | 1 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 10 | All Day Pass Reduced |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 10 | Other |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 10 | Reduced Fare |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 10 | Regular Cash Fare |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 101 | 10-Ride Pass |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 101 | 31-Day Adult |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 101 | All Day Pass Reduced |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| Route 101 | Other |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| Route 101 | Regular Cash Fare | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I am able to create the following table with the query included below, but I am missing the Route field which I need as part of my output (as shown above).

```
SELECT [Bus_Fare_Payment_Method] "Bus Fare Payment Method", [Under $10k] 'Under $10k', [$10K to $14K] '$10K to $14K',[$15k to $19k] '$15k to $19k', [$20k to $24k] '$20k to $24k', [$25k to $29k] '$25k to $29k', [$30k to $39k] '$30k to $39k', [$40k to $49k] '$40k to $49k', [$50k to $59k] '$50k to $59k', [$60k or more] '$60k or more'
FROM   
(SELECT [Route], [Total_Annual_Household_Income], [Bus_Fare_Payment_Method]  
FROM [BCT_TDP_SURVEY_2018] where [Bus_Fare_Payment_Method] != '' ) p  
PIVOT  
(  
COUNT ([Route])  
FOR [Total_Annual_Household_Income] IN  
( [Under $10k], [$10K to $14K],[$15k to $19k], [$20k to $24k], [$25k to $29k], [$30k to $39k], [$40k to $49k], [$50k to $59k], [$60k or more] )  
) AS pvt  
ORDER BY pvt.[Bus_Fare_Payment_Method]
```

| Bus_Fare_Payment_Method | $10K To $14K | $15K To $19K | $20K To $24K | $25K To $29K | $30K To $39K | $40K To $49K | $60K Or More | Under $10K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-Ride Pass |  | 2 |  | 1 | 1 |  | 1 |  |
| 31-Day Adult | 4 | 1 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| All Day Pass Reduced |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| Other |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| Reduced Fare | 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| Regular Cash Fare | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 8 |

Comment: You omitted it on your `SELECT`; of course it won't be there. In Though I suggest using conditional aggregation over the restrictive `Pivot` operator.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your quick response. I have tried that already with no luck. It returns the following error: Invalid column name 'Route'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you are far better off using conditional aggregation over the restrictive `PIVOT` operator:

```sql
SELECT Route,
       Bus_Fare_Payment_Method,
       COUNT(CASE Total_Annual_Household_Income WHEN '$15K To $19K' THEN 1 END) AS [$15K To $19K],
       COUNT(CASE Total_Annual_Household_Income WHEN '$25K To $29K' THEN 1 END) AS [$25K To $29K],
       ...
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Route,
         Bus_Fare_Payment_Method;
```